# NatTable IColumnAccessor.setDataValue is called twice

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, nattable

**Context**

I have implemented a NatTable (v1.1.0.201405012245) - please consider this simplified example:

```
package testproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.NatTable;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.AbstractRegistryConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.ConfigRegistry;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.EditableRule;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.IConfigRegistry;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.IColumnAccessor;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.IDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.ListDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.EditConfigAttributes;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.config.DefaultEditBindings;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.config.DefaultEditConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.editor.TextCellEditor;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.GridRegion;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.DataLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.LabelStack;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.cell.IConfigLabelAccumulator;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.selection.SelectionLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.selection.config.DefaultSelectionStyleConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.DisplayMode;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.viewport.ViewportLayer;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class ViewPart1 extends ViewPart
{
  @Override
  public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
  {
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");

    final IColumnAccessor<String> columnAccessor = new IColumnAccessor<String>()
    {
      @Override
      public void setDataValue(final String rowObject, final int columnIndex, final Object newValue)
      {
        if (!(newValue instanceof String) || ((String) newValue).contains("x"))
        {
          MessageDialog.openError(getSite().getShell(), "Error", "Invalid Input");
          return;
        }
        list.set(list.indexOf(rowObject), (String) newValue);
      }

      @Override
      public Object getDataValue(final String rowObject, final int columnIndex)
      {
        return rowObject;
      }

      @Override
      public int getColumnCount()
      {
        return 1;
      }
    };

    final IDataProvider dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(list, columnAccessor);
    final DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider);
    final SelectionLayer selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(dataLayer);
    final ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);

    final NatTable table = new NatTable(parent, viewportLayer, false);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(table);

    viewportLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultEditConfiguration());
    viewportLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultEditBindings());
    viewportLayer.setRegionName(GridRegion.BODY);

    viewportLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(new IConfigLabelAccumulator()
    {
      @Override
      public void accumulateConfigLabels(final LabelStack configLabels, final int columnPosition, final int rowPosition)
      {
        configLabels.addLabel("myLabel");
      }
    });

    table.setConfigRegistry(new ConfigRegistry());
    table.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
    table.addConfiguration(new DefaultSelectionStyleConfiguration());
    table.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration()
    {
      @Override
      public void configureRegistry(final IConfigRegistry registry)
      {
        registry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, new TextCellEditor(true), DisplayMode.NORMAL, "myLabel");
        registry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITABLE_RULE, EditableRule.ALWAYS_EDITABLE, DisplayMode.NORMAL, "myLabel");
      }
    });
    table.configure();
  }

  @Override
  public void setFocus()
  {
  }
}
```

Of course, this is not the real code, but my issue can be demonstrated with this code as well.

The important part is that in my actual project, when the user modifies a value, I need to update a model (including a complex tree of dependencies) and if that fails (e.g. in a numerical calculation the change results in a division by zero), I need to show an error (and revert to the previous value).

To show my core problem, in the code shown here I check for a simple condition in `IColumnAccessor#setDataValue` (the input contains an 'x') and show the error accordingly.

**Problem**

My actual problem is that if you enter an x into the TextCellEditor, the error dialog pops up twice (in sequence - meaning that as soon as I click ok for the first one, the second one will show).

**Analysis**

My analysis shows that the reason is that setDataValue is called twice:

1. because the ENTER key is pressed - Stacktrace

   - `TextCellEditor(AbstractCellEditor).commit(SelectionLayer$MoveDirectionEnum, boolean) line: 331`
   - `TextCellEditor(AbstractCellEditor).commit(SelectionLayer$MoveDirectionEnum) line: 326`
   - `TextCellEditor$1.keyPressed(KeyEvent) line: 246`
2. because the TextCellEditor loses focus - Stacktrace

   - `TextCellEditor(AbstractCellEditor).commit(SelectionLayer$MoveDirectionEnum, boolean, boolean) line: 341`
   - `TextCellEditor(AbstractCellEditor).commit(SelectionLayer$MoveDirectionEnum, boolean) line: 331`
   - `AbstractCellEditor$InlineFocusListener.focusLost(FocusEvent) line: 462`

So, my main question is: how can I prevent (or at least detect) the second event?

Comment: Could you remove or deregister one of the listeners, e.g. KeyPress listener?

Comment: @darijan any suggestions how? I don't register any listeners in the first place, it all happens inside of NatTable API...

Comment: I am really sorry, but no. I have a great deal of experience with swt.Tables and TextCellEditors, but not with this library... It was just an idea.

Comment: I could, maybe, subclass TextCellEditor and implement the behavior differently, but as it is implemented in the NatTable library, I guess there is a good reason ...

Comment: Okay, I think I found it. In this line `viewportLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultEditConfiguration());` I think you should override `DefaultEditConfiguration` (see docs here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/nattable/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.git/tree/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/edit/config/DefaultEditConfiguration.java)

Comment: Then, you could perhaps override this `TextCellEditor` for this line:  `configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, new TextCellEditor());`

Comment: If it works for you I can write an answer so it remains for other people with similar problems...

Comment: The TextCellEditor is not the problem and changing the configuration wouldn't change the behavior. The default configuration is not used as a special editor for a custom label is registered. You simply shouldn't perform validation inside the IColumnAccessor but use the validation/conversion handling of the NatTable framework as I explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your implementation is, that you are performing a conversion in the IColumnAccessor and open a dialog to inform the user about the error. But that is not the way to do this with NatTable because of various use cases.

If you need to perform conversion and/or validation you should register an appropriate IDisplayConverter and an IDataValidator. As you need a String you don't need to register a different converter, as the default converter that is registered via DefaultEditConfiguration is doing that already. So what you need is an IDataValidator that checks for the value x and throws a ValidationFailedException in that case. If you register the DialogErrorHandling as validation error handler, the error with the exception message will be shown in a dialog. And the checks for not opening the dialog twice is done internally.

This is explained in the (currently small) documentation http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=editing

BTW, I suggest to update to the latest NatTable release 1.3.0 as it also contains several bugfixes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the link. My problem is that in my case the business logic in the model is implemented in a way that I only know if the commit is completely consistent when I actually do commit (which writes to multiple files). And writing to files is something that shouldn't be done in a validatior ;-) I would agree that in an ideal system, validation and commit logic should be independent, but in this case we would be faced with a major refactoring. Is there any second best solution, maybe?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need some sort of "weak validation", because your model might contain "invalid" data until all data is set to be consistent. Is that correct? In that case you might want to have a look at the blog post I wrote about cross/weak validation in NatTable a while ago. http://blog.vogella.com/2013/03/02/crossweak-validation-in-nattable-by-dirk-fauth/